# reference generator website cannot put symbols or spaces between displayed content

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am designing a reference generator website and i am printing the text box value directly on the page but i am not able to integrate space or symbols between the 2 textbox displayed values 
please tell me how can i add symbols or spaces between the displayed content

this is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeThis(){
 var formInput = document.getElementById('theInput').value;
 document.getElementById('newText').innerHTML = formInput;
        var formInput = document.getElementById('theInput2').value;
 document.getElementById('newText2').innerHTML = formInput;
}

</script>

 
<input type='text' id='theInput' value='' />
<input type='text' id='theInput2' value='' />
<input type='button' onclick='changeThis()' value='generate'/>
<br>RESULT <span id='newText'></span><span id='newText2'></span> </p> 
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you want to put in between?? give an example

Answer (score 0):

Just use the hex entity `&#x20;`

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/1278p7c5/

Answer (score 0):

you can add span with style white-space:pre between 2 reults or you can add padding-left to second span,try this example by using white-space pre

```js
function changeThis(){
     var formInput = document.getElementById('theInput').value;
     document.getElementById('newText').innerHTML = formInput;
            var formInput = document.getElementById('theInput2').value;
     document.getElementById('newText2').innerHTML = formInput;
    }
 function changeThis(){
     var formInput = document.getElementById('theInput').value;
     document.getElementById('newText').innerHTML = formInput;
            var formInput = document.getElementById('theInput2').value;
     document.getElementById('newText2').innerHTML = formInput;
    }
```

```html
 <input type='text' id='theInput' value='' />
    <input type='text' id='theInput2' value='' />
    <input type='button' onclick='changeThis()' value='generate'/>
    <br>RESULT <span id='newText'></span><span style="white-space:pre">     </span><span id='newText2'></span> </p>
```